# Diagnosing non-functional steppers (Ender 3)

Tags: creality-ender-3, stepper-driver, stepper, skr-v1.4

I was upgrading my (already very modified) Ender 3 with a geared extruder, and figured instead of re-flashing the firmware, why not switch the extruder phase on the cable?  I accidentally shorted the two coils together instead of swapping within one phase, and now none of the stepper motors work properly (this is with TMC2208s on an SKR 1.4).

The current behavior is that when I try to move any axis (including the extruder), the motor will align with the nearest step (I assume) and then not move any further.

I'm trying to figure out if I trashed the mainboard, if I somehow managed to destroy all my stepper drivers with a single extrude command (which seems less likely), or if there is an easy fix I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that resetting the board after reflashing the firmware fixed the issue.

(Then I dropped a spring on the board and totally killed it an hour later).

Comment: Sorry to hear you fried the board after fixing it. But, thanks for answering your own question, please accept the answer after 48 hours! Thanks!